# Ein ICE fährt um 14 Uhr. What is subject, verb and direct object and why does it not take akkusativ case

Tags: accusative

> Ein ICE fährt um 14 Uhr.

What is subject, verb and direct object and why does it not take accusative case?

Whereas another sentence

> Gibt es keinen Zug heute morgen?

takes accusative?  Please state what is subject, verb and direct object in this second example.

I've been working on this for a while but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Why do you believe there are objects involved? Consider the sentence: „the train leaves tomorrow“!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very unclear how the op settled on the notion of objects

Comment: You could improve your question with an edit that adds, what you think is subject, verb and object and why you think so. Don't worry if you think it's wrong, but this might help people to understand how you are thinking and where you might err.

Comment: There is nothing like "direct object" or "indirect object" in German. German has "Akkusativobjekt" (er sieht den Mann), "Dativobjekt" (es gehört dem Mann), "Genitivobjekt" (sie gedenkt des Mannes), "Nominativobjekt" (er ist ein Mann) and "Präpositionalobjekt" (er wartet auf den Mann). Even "adverbiale Bestimmung" looks like an object (but isn't) (er wartet auf dem Platz) . But you won't find the terms "direktes Objekt" or "indirektes Objekt" in any German grammar book.

Answer (score 4):

Your sample sentence is:

> Der Zug fährt um 14 Uhr.

There is no object in this sentence.

***Ein ICE*** is your subject.

***fährt*** is your verb

***um 14 Uhr*** is what according to usual German school grammar nomenclature is called *eine adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit*, i.e. something used to give more details to the action, here regarding time, but it could also be regarding place or whatever. - The action of a sentence is expressed chiefly by the verb, hence "adverb" which means "to the verb".

If you want to have a sentence with an object, here is one:

> Der Zug überfährt **den Bahnübergang** um 14 Uhr.

*(etwas) überfahren* is a verb that usually asks for an object, in this case an accusative object ("direct object" if you want). You cannot use *überfahren* without an object, so

> *Der Zug überfährt um 14 Uhr.

is not a well-formed sentence, meaning: native speakers will look puzzled and think: "Huh? Something has gone wrong with that sentence!"

Answer (score 1):

Christian Geiselmann already said it in [his answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46416/1487): There is no object in the first sentence, according to German grammar. Maybe it may be called "direct object" if translated into other languages, but German has nothing like direct objects.

Do not think in terms like *direct* or *indirect* object whan you think about German grammar. This may help often, but sometimes (like in your example) it is misleading! Better learn the terms used in German grammar.

---

German has nothing that is called »direktes Objekt« or »indirektes Objekt«. This term may fit in other languages, but German grammar has grammatical cases, and we classify objects by cases.

What you call a direct object, is most often one of these:

- an accusative object (**Akkusativobjekt**)
  This is an object in accusative case, like needed for verbs like *sehen* (to see), *anklagen* (to accuse, this is where the name comes from) and others.

  > Ich sehe **den Mann.**
  >   Der Staatsanwalt klagt **den Mann** an.
- a prepositional object (**Präpositionalobjekt**)
  This is an object in none of the four cases, beginning with a preposition, followed by a nominal group in accusative or dative case, often seen after verbs like *denken* (to think), or *diskutieren* (to discuss).

  > Ich denke **an den Mann.**
  >   Ich diskutiere **mit dem Mann.**
- an adverbial determination (**adverbiale Bestimmung**)
  This isn't even an object, but looks similar to prepositional objects, and is found at almost all verbs. Your example belongs to this group.

  > Er steht **auf dem Platz.**
  >   Der Zug fährt **um 14 Uhr.**

What you call an *indirect object* is most often

- a dative object (**Dativobjekt**)
  This is an object in dative case, and it is needed for words like *gehören* (to belong to) or geben (to give, the name comes from latin verb *dare (do das dare dedi datum)* which means to give)

  > Es gehört **dem Mann.**
  >   Ich gebe es **dem Mann.**

But German also has genitive objects (**Gentivobjekt**), as needed for verbs like *gedenken* (to commemorate) or *bedürfen* (to need) which are neither direct nor indirect.

> Die Gemeinde gedenkt **der Toten.**
>   Die Opfer bedürfen **der Hilfe.**

Also nominative objects (**Nominativobjekt**) are neither direct not indirect. You more often find the name *Gleichsetzungsnominativ* for it. Verbs like *sein* (to be) or *bleiben* (to stay) need it.

> Ich bin **ein Mann.**
>   Er bleibt **der Chef.**

---

analysis of your sentences:

- > **Ein ICE fährt um 14 Uhr.**

  - **ein ICE**
    Subjekt im Nominativ, Einzahl
  - **fährt**
    Verb in der Gegenwart, 3. Person, Einzahl
  - **um 14 Uhr**
    adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit
- > **Gibt es keinen Zug heute morgen?**

  - **gibt**
    Verb in der Gegenwart, 3. Person, Einzahl
  - **es**
    Subjekt im Nominativ, Einzahl (expletives Pronomen)
  - **keinen Zug**
    Akkusativobjekt, Einzahl
  - **heute morgen**
    adverbiale Bestimmung des Verbs

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich habe schon »adverbiale Bestimmung des Verbs« gemeint, denn die Wortgruppe bestimmt das Verb näher. So wie auch im zweiten Satz, wo »heute morgen« das Verb »geben« näher bestimmt, und nicht den Zug oder gar das Substantiv. Dass die Bestimmung eine temporale ist, ist natürlich auch richtig, das wollte ich aber nicht zum Ausdruck bringen. Das blöde ist nur, dass jetzt dasselbe Element in einem Satz als »adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit« und im anderen als »adverbiale Bestimmung des Verbs« bezeichnet wird. Ich überlasse es dir zu entscheiden, wie damit umzugehen ist.

Comment: Danke für die Erläuterung, und ich bitte um Verzeihung für die dann unautorisierte Einmischung meinerseits. Der Text soll natürlich so formuliert sein, wie Du es für richtig hältst. Ich dachte, du hättest dich einfach vertippt. - Allerdings, zur inhaltlichen Diskussion: Ergibt "adverbiale Bestimmung des Verbs" denn einen Sinn? "Adverbial" sagt doch schon, dass es "zum Verb" gehört (und nicht zu ewas anderem). Dann ist "des Verbs" doch redundant?

Comment: Das erscheint jenen als redundant, die mit dem Begriff vertraut sind. Denen, die die Sprache und die grammatischen Termini lernen, wird der Hinweis, dass sich die adverbiale Bestimmung auf das Verb (und nicht vielleicht auf ein Objekt) bezieht, vielleicht hilfreich erscheinen. Denn zumindest Adverbien (deren Haupteinsatzgebiet die adverbialen Bestimmungen sind) können auch Begleiter von anderen Wortarten sein, z.B. von Adjektiven (der *einst* schöne Mantel).